# Opencart "store change" php code

Tags: opencart, multiple-languages, multistore

Is there any php code to change store? So for example if php detects the language is Spanish I would like it to change the whole store to other store.

So it can be used for example anytime when language is changed - then the store is changed also.
So for example if anyone is viewing the store1 in English and change language to Spanish then automatically the store1 is also changed to store2 toghether with the language. Any idea?

Comment: In theory you could use a redirect Javascript that executes on the "change" event of the language selector. I'm assuming the store URLs are different?

Comment: Yes, there are different URLs - stores will be set on different domains or just on some subdomains. Probably you are right with this Javascript code but it seems that it is to difficult for me to write it.

Comment: Why don't you share the store URL so that anyone looking can give their insight, or at least the `catalog/view/theme/<<themname>>/common/header.tpl` (or .twigg) file that should show the language selector. I can assist with code for the default template but if you're not using it and aren't good with code then you may still find it difficult.

Comment: I cannot share URL because I don't yet have a store and a domain :) I am testing some modules and solutions with basic template and when all what I desire is accomplished a new store will be created. I believe if I had a piece of code working with basic store and default template I could apply it to any new store. So if language is "es", change store to "store1.example.com", if language code is "aaa" change to "store2"... - this is what I would need.

Comment: Okay, if you're confident to implement based off an example, which version of OC are you using?

Comment: 2.2, I will buy you a good cup of coffee if this will be successful

Comment: After playing around with one of my test sites, I think it might just be simpler to have your own HTML markup with a combobox, each option value will have the store URL and there can be a simple script following that. What do you think?

Comment: If there were a comobox for changing stores, there would be a need to delete language changes in the store at the top of any page and then add a code for a defined language change each time a store is changed. It is the same but the other way round. It would be easier to add simple code to change store each time when language is changed. But it must preserve certain pages so when we have store1.example.com/product-aaa we should get after changing a language store2.example.com/product-aaa.

Comment: That's the ideal solution, I've played around with the existing language switcher and it's not as straightforward as that. Trying to use `event.preventDefault();` proved unsuccessful. I don't know how often you plan on adding or removing the languages but this is a fairly simple task over writing one line in each store template's header file. Perhaps someone else has a better solution?

Answer (score 2):

If you open file: index.php or startup.php (based on the OpenCart version you use) you will see that there is a code that checks the url of which the user has visited and then searches the database to see if it's default store (store_id = 0) or other store. If it's the default store, then nothing changes. If it's not though, then session variable (store_id) is changed to the specified store_id and the whole opencart will operate based on this store_id.

**OpenCart 1.5.x** index.php

```
// Store
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && (($_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on') || ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] == '1'))) {
    $store_query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "store WHERE REPLACE(`ssl`, 'www.', '') = '" . $db->escape('https://' . str_replace('www.', '', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) . rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '/.\\') . '/') . "'");
} else {
    $store_query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "store WHERE REPLACE(`url`, 'www.', '') = '" . $db->escape('http://' . str_replace('www.', '', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) . rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '/.\\') . '/') . "'");
}

if ($store_query->num_rows) {
    $config->set('config_store_id', $store_query->row['store_id']);
} else {
    $config->set('config_store_id', 0);
}
```

**OpenCart 2.x / 3.x** - catalog/controller/startup/startup.php

```
// Store
        if ($this->request->server['HTTPS']) {
            $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "store WHERE REPLACE(`ssl`, 'www.', '') = '" . $this->db->escape('https://' . str_replace('www.', '', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) . rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '/.\\') . '/') . "'");
        } else {
            $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "store WHERE REPLACE(`url`, 'www.', '') = '" . $this->db->escape('http://' . str_replace('www.', '', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) . rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '/.\\') . '/') . "'");
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['store_id'])) {
            $this->config->set('config_store_id', (int)$this->request->get['store_id']);
        } else if ($query->num_rows) {
            $this->config->set('config_store_id', $query->row['store_id']);
        } else {
            $this->config->set('config_store_id', 0);
        }
```

So, you can extend this code and you will check the browser's language and based on every language you will change the store_id to the one you need.

A sample code is the following, it's not the ideal, but it will give you the idea on how to implement it by yourself.

```
$lang = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);

switch ($lang){
    case "fr":
$this->config->set('config_store_id', 1);
        break;
    case "it":
$this->config->set('config_store_id', 2);
        break;
    case "en":
$this->config->set('config_store_id', 3);
        break;   
    case "el":
$this->config->set('config_store_id', 4);
        break;        
    default:
        //else default store
$this->config->set('config_store_id', 0);
        break;
}
```

Hope the above answer will help you. It's easy, but you need to understand how OpenCart works. Also, just my advice..."Don't wait for ready-made extensions, try to make yours." ;)

Cheers!

Comment: Konstantinos, it is not exactly what I wanted, but it works very well and helps a lot. It is very probable that I will use it instead what I wanted before. Thank you.
I though previously that maybe it is possible not only to change stores, but also subdomains. Stores work on different subdomains such as store1.example.com, store2.example.com. So when I am on store1 and change it to language which is ascribed to store2, yes, it changes also to store2 but on the first subdomain (store1.example.com). Probably there should be a way to have it changed at the same time to store2.example.com.

Comment: Even if this can be OK in some circumstances, this cannot be applied if I would like to have stores on different domains as example1.com and example1.fr I would then changes languages and stores within one domain - what I would like to have is one domain or subdomain for one language for one store and all connected together in admin panel. Your solution works practically as one language for a store but within only one domain.

Comment: You can change the code according to your needs. For example, if you don't want the same code for every store, then you can filter the selected store_id and then redirect or not. Or you can have an array and check if language = en and store_id = 0 is ok , no redirect, but if language = en and store_id = 3 then redirect to store_id = 0 .